# Mobile Web: Request user's location when GPS is turned off

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation

I'm building a mobile web app that incorporates GeoLocation.  On the Android browser (OS 2.0+) if the user has GPS turned off, a request from my web app to get their location does NOT show up.  If their GPS is turned on, then a location permission request does show up.

I know that requesting a user's location from the browser when GPS is off is possible as [Gowalla's mobile web app](http://m.gowalla.com) is able to trigger the request.  I looked through their sprocket.js file and it looks pretty straight forward.  Any ideas what the secret is here?

Answer (score 0):

They just try different frameworks (Google Gears, Blackberry, and so on) and if one works they use it.
If GPS is deactivated you can either use the the last location (if it's not too old) or in the worst case you can try something with the IP and a geolocation-DB, although the results won't be accurate at all.

Comment: When I was looking through their code I was also seeing multiple trys.  I still can't figure out what is triggering the location request when the user's GPS is off.  Google Gears is not supported on Android 2.x (http://gears.google.com/?platform=android) and the regular W3C geolocation is not triggering the request when GPS is off.  I don't see anything else in their code that would trigger the request on an Android device...

Answer (score 0):

You could start a location manager in your java before you call the web view. As long as you have the have the fine location access in your manifest, you might be able to turn on geolocation.

Comment: May i ask a question - how what java code is needed to get the GEo permission request? - i don't see any request when a i run a web page from a web app, but do see a request when i run the url in a broswer? thanks @ARolek

Comment: Yes  the mystical GEo permission request code ..has anyone got it working! yes i tried and failed..but..i got GPS working in a web page by starting a location service in java , and then polling the loaction via js interface from the web page timer event not pretty and not using the wc3 js navigator!